# Вызов дочернего метода через базовый класс

Tags: c++, ооп, виртуальная-функция

Есть базовый класс `Shapes`, в нем есть два абстрактных метода `P` (Периметр) и `S` (Площадь). Также есть дочерний класс `Circle`, в котором реализованы методы `P` и `S` с помощью полиморфизма.

Вопрос: как вызвать метод `P` и `S` из класса `Circle` через класс `Shapes`?

Это же называется динамическое связывание?

*Shapes.h*

```
class Shpes
{
private:    
public:
    Shpes();
    virtual double P() = 0;
    virtual double S() = 0;
};

Shpes::Shpes()
{

}
```

*Circle.h*

```
#include "Shpes.h"

class Circle :
    public Shpes
{
private: 
    double r;
    void SetCheck(double R);

public: 
    Circle(double R = 0);
    virtual double P();
    virtual double S();
    void Print();
};
```

*Circle.cpp*

```
#include "Circle.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Circle::SetCheck(double R)
{
    R < 0 ? r = abs(R) : r = R; 
}

Circle::Circle(double R)
{
    SetCheck(R);
}

double Circle::P()
{   
    return 2 * 3.12 * r;
}

double Circle::S()
{   
    return 3.14 * r * r;
}

void Circle::Print()
{
    cout << "При радиусе круга = " << r <<endl<< "Периметр P = " << P()<<endl<<"Площадь S = " << S();
}
```

Comment: На всякий случай: "пи" в формуле для периметра имеет то же значение, что и для площади :) Кстати, лучше определить это значение как `const double PI = 3.1415926;`, и использовать в формулах уже именованную константу.

Comment: @Harry, а я и не заметил. Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это можно сделать через указатель или ссылку на базовый класс, инициализированными объектом производного класса.

Например,

```
Circle c( 10 );

Shape *ps = &c;

ps->R();
ps->S();

Shape &rs = c;

rs.R();
rs.S();
```

Имейте в виду, что деструктор в базовом классе также следует объявить как виртуальный. Например,

```
virtual ~Shape() = default;
```

или

```
virtual ~Shape(){}
```

ОБратите внимание на расхождение

```
double Circle::P()
{   
    return 2 * 3.12 * r;
              ^^^^^
}

double Circle::S()
{   
    return 3.14 * r * r;
           ^^^^
}
```

Чтобы не допускать такого вида ошибки, лучше используемым константам назначать имена. Вы могли бы определить соответствующий член в вашем классе (при условии, что компилятор поддерживает данную конструкцию), например,

```
class Circle :
    public Shpes
{
private: 
    double r;
    void SetCheck(double R);
    constexpr static double PI = 3.14;

public: 
    Circle(double R = 0);
    virtual double P();
    virtual double S();
    void Print();
};
```

И записать определения функций следующим образом

```
double Circle::P()
{   
    return 2 * PI * r;
              ^^^^^
}

double Circle::S()
{   
    return PI * r * r;
           ^^^^
}
```

Если компилятор не поддерживает такое объявление члена класса, то можно просто написать

```
class Circle :
    public Shpes
{
private: 
    double r;
    void SetCheck(double R);
    const static double PI;

public: 
    Circle(double R = 0);
    virtual double P();
    virtual double S();
    void Print();
};
```

И затем определить эту статическую переменную

```
    double Circle::PI = 3.14;
```

Answer (score 0):

Очень просто:

```
Shpes *figure = new Circle( 1 );
cout << figure->P() << endl;
```